# python StopIteration with Generators and lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, exception, generator

Following Jean's answer to my question on: [Python converting strings in a list to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695440/python-converting-strings-in-a-list-to-numbers) , I get a `StopIteration` exception when running the below minimal code.

`primes` and `z2` are empty.

From googling I think I may need a while loop around the line in traceback but I'm not sure how to remedy?

Traceback:

```
File "factorise_v32.py", line 118, in factorise
    primes=[next(z2) for _ in xrange(b)]  
StopIteration
```

Sample data in CSV file:

```
("2","3","5","7","11")
```

Minimal Code:

```
import csv

def factorise(N)
    ....
    z1=(int(x) for row in csv.reader(csvfile) for x in row)
    ....
    b=4 #b can be any positive integer
    z2=(int(x) for row in csv.reader(csvfile) for x in row)
    primes=[next(z2) for _ in xrange(b)]
```

Comment: `next()` raises the exception because `z2` is exhausted. There are no `b` elements in `z2`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would the `StopIteration` not be handled in order to terminate the comprehension?

Comment: Why not iterate *directly* over `z2`? Make it a list comprehension, or use `slice()` if you want to get a limited number of elements.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: no, that's not how a list comprehension works. It is not `xrange()` that raises the `StopIteration` and a list comprehension is not a generator.

Comment: OP only wants to read file up to first `b` elements. Maybe `csvfile` has reached `EOF` because you're calling this with the same file handle?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: at which point `islice()` is better tool.

Comment: @martjiin can you give an answer for this using `slice()` or list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension is not a generator or iterator itself. It will not stop when the expression side raises a `StopIteration` exception. The *iterable* that `for ... in <iterable>` loops over can use `StopIteration` to communicate to the `for` loop that iteration is done, but that doesn't extend to the rest of the construct.

If you need to get *at most* `b` number of elements from an iterator, use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
primes = list(islice(z2, b))
```

It'll take up to `b` elements when iterated over, or less if there are not enough elements in `z2`.

An earlier revision of the post you linked to tried to *pad out* the result with `0` values in case there were fewer than `b` elements by giving `next()` a default value. I'd have used [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) and [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to achieve this:

```
primes = list(islice(chain(z2, repeat(0)), b))
```

The `chain(z2, repeat(0))` part will endlessly add `0` values after `z2` is exhausted. `islice()` takes `b` elements from that sequence.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat, islice
>>> z2 = iter([1, 2, 3])
>>> list(islice(z2, 5))  # up to 5
[1, 2, 3]
>>> z2 = iter([1, 2, 3])  # pad with zeros
>>> list(islice(chain(z2, repeat(0)), 5))
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
```

Note that you *can't read from a CSV file twice in a row*, not without rewinding the file object first. Your code is using `csv.reader(csvfile)` in two locations, but the `csvfile` file object does not go back to the start. Add `csvfile.seek(0)` before trying to read from it again.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: wording adjusted.

Comment: perfect as always :) did you perform a "I'm not a pybot" on yourself lately ?

Comment: @Jean ssssh! His programming may break if he finds out he actually is! :p

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this behaviour was only introduced in recent years by [PEP479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)?

Comment: doesn't seem to be related: " when StopIteration is raised inside a generator, it is replaced it with RuntimeError". just changes the exception type

Comment: @schwobaseggl: did I mention already that a list comprehension is *not a generator*? Note that the OP is using `xrange()`, this is Python 2.7.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see your point now. I was kind of under the impression that a list comprehension `[x for x in ...]` was just syntactic sugar for `list(x for x in ...)`. But this constitutes a clear case where the two have different outcomes let alone any implementational details.

Comment: @martijn I get an empty primes list when using `primes = list(islice(z2, b))`

Comment: Ok now I don't understand why `z2` is empty, since I've used pretty much the same line earlier in my code called `z1` that works fine. I will update this question.

Comment: @unseen_rider: you can iterate over an iterator **just once**. You probably already iterated over it. If you fed it a file, then the file position needs to be at the start, if you read from it already the file position will be at the end and no more data will be read.

Comment: I'm thinking if I change `x` and `int(x)` to `y` and `int(y)` for`z2` should this make it work?

Comment: @unseen_rider: your question update didn't clarify anything and I rolled it back in the interest of keeping question and answer clear. I'm pretty sure this is an issue with your CSV file.

Comment: @unseen_rider: You are using `csv.reader(csvfile)` twice; `csvfile` will be at the end of the file if you have read from it enough through `z1`. So when you use it a second time so it'll produce *no data*, or very little data if you did not read all of it (the `csv.reader()` will *buffer* data from the underlying file so it'll read more than you may actually use).

Comment: @unseen_rider: ah, your edit did show you used `list(z1)`, so *all* data was read from `csvfile`. So no, you can't then use `csvfile` again without going back to the start. Why not reuse the data from `z1` however? You have a list there with all the values from the CSV file, why read it all again?

Comment: Good point thanks for your help. I see this can be done via `csvfile seek(0)` from your updated answer. +1

Comment: @unseen_rider check the new version (earlier today) of my answer. I was suggesting to be careful not to consume the iterator twice as well.